# Ruby on Rails: How to make a next/prev page button for post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to make a next/prev button for a page that is listing posts (without gem). I want to limit it to 8 per page (newest to oldest).
For the controller I have this:

```
def index
    @links = Link.order(created_at: :desc).limit(8).offset(@page * 8)
end

private
def set_page
    @page = params[:page] || 0
end
```

In the index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Prev Page', page: -1.to_i %>
<%= link_to 'Next Page', page: +1.to_i %>
```

It listed 8 topics on the first page but when I click next page, its just a blank page. I followed this from another post but I'm not sure what I missed.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look, if you don't want use gem then follow the following code like in the controller

```
before_action :set_page, only: [:index]
PAGE_SIZE = 8
def index
    @links = Link.order(created_at: :desc).offset(PAGE_SIZE * @page).limit(PAGE_SIZE)
end


private
def set_page
    @page = (params[:page] || 0).to_i
end
```

and in the view

```
<nav>
    <ul class="pager">
        <li class="previous <%= page == 0 ? 'disabled' : '' %>">
            <%= link_to_if page > 0, "&larr; Previous".html_safe, your_index_path(page: page - 1) %>
        </li>
        <li class="next">
            <%= link_to "Next &rarr;".html_safe, your_index_path(page: page + 1) %>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Glad to hear it :)